# Write a file in /var/lib/sysnews/

Tags: permissions, sudo

In that folder are stored the `news` files: they can be created by the system administrator to write some informations for the users, as suggested in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/487759/linux-one-time-message-on-login) link.

I tried as a normal user to add a file in `/var/lib/sysnews`, but nor this command

```
echo "Hello world" > /var/lib/sysnews
```

neither this command

```
sudo echo "Hello world" > /var/lib/sysnews
```

worked (it gives *permission denied* error).

The folder is owned by `root` user and by the `staff` group. My normal user was already in the `sudo` group; I added the `staff` group for my user, but with no results.

I can add news only by creating a file in one of my folders and then typing

```
sudo mv myfile /var/lib/sysnews
```

but it is bothering.

Is there a simpler way to add some news file to that folder without being root?

Comment: Please update answer with the contents of /var/lib/sysnews, i.e. `ls -al /var/lib/sysnews`

Comment: Summary: you can use any of `echo "Hello World" | sudo tee -a /var/lib/sysnews` or `sudo sh -c "echo \"Hello World\" > /var/lib/sysnews"` or switch to root with `sudo -i`.

Comment: yes sorry, I thought there was a way in the `news` command  or similar to post news without being root: this is why I didn't looked for piping answers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be from redirecting/piping output. Use your favorite editor (vim in my case) and `sudo vim /var/lib/sysnews` and edit the file through an editor invoked with `sudo`. Or use one of the `sudo commandline` redirect workarounds listed above, but none of those seem like the 'simpler' answer.